# Probability of drawing colored Marbles

Tags: probability

A bag contains 7 red, 6 green and 5 blue marbles. 3 marbles are drawn.
What is the probability of drawing 2 red marbles if the marbles are drawn one by one without replacement?

Comment: I would answer the question, but it's gonna get closed sooner than later, so it's not worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

There's a trick to these questions which comes in handy: labeling the identically colored marbles.  What is the probability of drawing two red marbles from the set $$\{R_1,R_2,\ldots,R_7,G_1,G_2,\ldots,G_6,B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_5\}?$$  It's the same probability as the original question.

There are two possibilities:

1. We choose exactly two red marbles and choose one non-red marble, whence $\mathrm{Pr}(\text{two red, one non-red})=\frac{\binom{???}{???} \binom{???}{???}}{\binom{7+6+5}{3}}$, and
2. We choose exactly three red marbles, whence $\mathrm{Pr}(\text{three red marbles})=\frac{\binom{???}{???}}{\binom{7+6+5}{3}}$.

(You may or may not want to include the second possibility, it depends on how the question is interpreted.)

Since these are mutually exclusive, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Pr}(\text{two red, one non-red} \cup \text{three red}) = \mathrm{Pr}(\text{two red, one non-red})+\mathrm{Pr}(\text{three red}).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{7}{18} \cdot \frac{6}{17} \cdot \frac{16}{16}$$

Everytime you take a red a marble you're removing one from the overall count so subtract 1 each time since you're not replacing. The last one you would just multiply by 1 since it doesn't matter what you get.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on typesetting mathematics on this site.

Comment: Be careful.  You calculated the probability of obtaining red marbles on each of the first two draws.